# why std::string is zero initialized to indeterminate value

Tags: c++, static, initialization, stdstring

The following code example is from cppreference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

```
#include <string>

double f[3]; // zero-initialized to three 0.0's
int* p;   // zero-initialized to null pointer value
std::string s; // zero-initialized to indeterminate value
               // then default-initialized to ""
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static int n = argc; // zero-initialized to 0
                         // then copy-initialized to argc
    delete p; // safe to delete a null pointer
}
```

It says std::string is zero initialized to **indeterminate** value. The same page also says for a non-union class type, all non static members are zero initialized.

Without knowing the implementation details of std::string, I would think it has a member of char* which stores the actual string value. If that's the case, shouldn't the char* be zero initialized to null pointer, and if so then why the value is indeterminate?

Comment: (1) There is no requirement for `std::string` to have a `char*` member; (2) even if there is one, `std::string` is likely to contain other, unspecified data members that have unspecified types and semantics.

Comment: "Without knowing the implementation details" - exactly. They're not specified, so there's no way to say whether zero-initialisation gives a valid object.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please give an example what types will have unspecified data when being zero-initialized. I'm a bit confused by the "zero" part, according to the standard all scalar types zero are converted from integer zero, pointers are set to null, etc.

Comment: @swang: Who said anything about unspecified data? As you say, the value of whatever scalar types make up the object's internal representation is well specified; but without a constructor to establish a valid state, that might or might not give a valid `string` object, hence an indeterminate value for that object.

Comment: I was just commenting the above when you said they are not specified. I get the point that a zero-initialized std::string is not usable/valid, just wish the standard or cppreference can state it more obviously. They did mention using default initialized indeterminate non-class type value is undefined behaviour, but didn't say anything about zero initialized indeterminate class type. value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic constituents are zero-initialized, but what those zero-values *mean* for `std::string`, if anything, depends entirely on the implementation.

The dynamic initialization invokes the `std::string` constructor and establishes the class invariant (the basic assumptions about the internal state of the instance).

Only after that are the values such that the object is guaranteed usable.

Comment: @vz0: please check out the section of the standard dealing with initialization of static variables. they're zero-initialized regardless of kind of type, before dynamic initialization. apparently in C++11 it's §3.6.2. sorry i don't have much time.

Comment: @vz0: Yes it is. All non-local variables are zero-initialised during static initialisation, before dynamic initialisation begins. Quoting C++11 3.6.2/2: "**Variables with static storage duration** or thread storage duration **shall be zero-initialized**
before any other initialization takes place."

Comment: so basically even a static const std::string is zero-initialized, it's still not usable until the constructor is called? That means I can not use a statc const std::string at static initialization stage, but I can if it's a const char* ?

Comment: @swang: basically yes. but watch out for the *static initialization order fiasco*.